# Reading Excel Files in Python over network share is very slow

Tags: excel, performance, python-2.7, xlrd

I am using xlrd library with Python to read approx 200 small Excel files over a UNC network share.  The process of opening the Excel files is very slow. I made a simple benchmark program to measure how long it takes to just open the Excel files without actually doing anything else.

The timer reports that it takes 92 seconds to read 100 Excel files that are 50KB in size each. Why is this taking so long to run? Over a wireless connection accessing the same network share, it takes almost 2-3 minutes!

Eventually I need to save some data from the Excel workbooks, and then write a new Excel file with the collected information. Am I doing something wrong that is slowing this down?

```
import time
import sys
import os
import re
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname, XLRDError
from xlwt import Workbook
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def ReadReports():
    start = timer()
    filename_pattern = re.compile('^Report_name_.*')

    count =0
    root_directory = r'//network/path/somedirectory'

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
        files[:] = [f for f in files if re.match(filename_pattern,f)]

        for file in files:
            count+=1

            try:
                #get the input file object (open the excel workbook)
                fullpath = os.path.join(path,file)
                book = open_workbook(fullpath)

            except IOError: 
                logger.exception('Program encountered IOError')
                continue

            except XLRDError as e:
                logger.exception('Program encountered XLRDError')
                continue

            else:
                pass


    print "num files: ", count
    end = timer()
    print "time: %r seconds" %(end - start)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReadReports()
```

Comment: Is there something unclear about my question? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, here's some things you could try:

1. Convert all your excel files to csv, and work with that. Reading csv files is generally faster than reading excel workbooks
2. Right click the folder that you're working in and try - 'make available offline' That'll save a copy on your C drive, making accessing the files a bit faster.